# Floating menu with jquery by using scrollTop()

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, menu

I am new to jquery and yesterday I was trying to make my own floating menu with jquery because I couldn't get satisfactory results with css. But the code that I wrote didn't worked. Can you guys please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

What I want to do is the menu should reappear and stay in the top when I've gone down a few pixels.

Here's the jquery code I'm using:-

```
var menu = function(){
    var x=$(body).scrollTop();
    if(x>10){
        $('header').animate({position:fixed},100);
    }
    else{
        $('header').animate({position:static},100);
    }
}

$(document).ready(menu);
```

Comment: Can you post your html?

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need jQuery for that task.
Listen for a `"scroll"` and `"resize"` eventNames, and toggle a class on your #menu when a condition is met (`y > 10`).
I'll use 100px in this demo:

```js
const elMenu = document.querySelector("#menu");

const handleMenu = () => {
  const { scrollY } = window;
  elMenu.classList.toggle("sticky", scrollY > 100);
};

addEventListener("resize", handleMenu);
addEventListener("scroll", handleMenu);
handleMenu();
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/ * { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

body{
  height: 300vh;
  border: dashed #000;
  border-width: 0 4px 0 4px;
}

#menu {
  position: relative;
  background: orange;
  padding: 2rem;
  
  &.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
  #menu will reappear after 100px scroll
</nav>
```